# Linking to a .a c++ Library in an Objective-C Project

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode4.5, static-linking

I'm trying to add support for iZotope (audio effects) in an Objective-C application.

During integration, I've ran into a number of problems related to linking the iZotope C++ library into my Xcode project.

As of this point I haven't done nothing else than:

- Add the libraries (.a) in TARGETS > MyTargetName > Build Phases > Link Binaries with Libraries
- Add the header files of the library to PROJECT > MyProjectName > Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search Paths

I haven't written any code, at all.  My goal for now is to get my project to compile, as it was before adding the libraries.

Here is a link to the compiler output (https://gist.github.com/dornad/6310107).  To me it seems that Xcode has no idea about the c++ std library, so it fails spectacularly.

Any ideas?

Comment: For the new library you will also need to add a Library Search Path. That property is right next to Header search path. From a compiler standpoint, you need a "-l" flag to specify the filename, you've done that by putting it in Link Binaries with Libraries, you will also need "-L" that tells the compiler where to search for that library hence the Library Search Path property.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  So if my file is libCoreFXSim.a, I need to add -LlibCoreFXSim under Library Search Path, right?

Comment: Sorry I confused you. If next to your XCodeProject, you have a folder called CoreFX and in it you have your lib called "libCoreFXSim.a", you would add "$(SRCROOT)/CoreFX" to your **Library Search Paths**. SRCROOT and other variables are documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html). That way XCode will think of searching in that folder when looking for your library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard C++ libraries can not be found. Probably, the extension of your project files is `.m` instead of `.mm`, which is necessary for c++ compilation.

Comment: I was reading about creating a Objective-C wrapper around the C++ library.  I'd like to keep files as they are (.m), instead of switching to .mm, as explained here:  http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++

Comment: Or rather, can I keep mix .mm and .m in one project?  i.e. the wrapper around the C++ library would be Objective-C++ and the rest of the project will remain as it is?

Comment: Yes you can, that's what I'm doing in my project in Cocos2d-x. I have mostly CPP files, some .MM that act as a bridge (mix C++ with Obj-C) and a few .M files when I really need pure Obj-C code. .M is compiled with a Objective-C compiler whereas .MM is compiled with a Objective-C++ compiler. The Objective-C compiler doesn't know about Standard C++ libs.